# Drupal: on node save, redirect user to homepage?

Tags: nodes, redirection

How can I redirect the user to the home page (or another drupal page) on node save instead of them seeing the saved content?

Comment: Hello. Drupal 6? 7?

Answer (score 4):

The [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) will help you.

If you found a problem with using this module and you want to know how to do this technically, just tell me and I will explain in detail.

Comment: @melissa, review this resource http://drupal.org/node/794280 is a tutorial, step by step about how to *Redirect to a page when user submit form* using Rules

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to the code reported in [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/130734#comment-3547388), which is for Drupal 6; similar code can be used for Drupal 7, but it needs to be adjusted to it (e.g. `hook_nodeapi()` is not used with Drupal 7).

```
function mymodulename_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  global $user;
  switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':
      if ($node->type == 'h_energy_feedback' && $user->uid == 0) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Your feedback has been saved. Thanks for taking the time!'));
        drupal_goto();
      } else {
        drupal_set_message(t('The feedback was saved.'));
        drupal_goto('forms/henergy-feedback');
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Using drupal_goto() will stop rest of the following code from getting executed, which could get you into trouble. Much better would be to use for example already suggested Rules.